# Can I set the SoapHttpClientProtocol Timeout property via a config file?

Tags: c#, .net, settings, client-side, webservice-client

When I create the web reference for a web service, Visual Studio magically creates a Settings class which allows me to change the referenced web service URL via the application config.  Very useful for changing between development and production servers without rebuilding code.

I haven't been able to find a similar mechanism for the Timeout (or any other) property.  Is there one?

(For clarity: I'm talking about the client-side code, with a web service reference derived from SoapHttpClientProtocol.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could using the Settings feature to define your own settings for Timeout and other properties.  You could then write the code to read the property rather than a magic number right in your code.

Comment: I was hoping to stick to using the code generated from the WSDL.  That already takes care of the settings for one property, but it looks as though the default code only initializes Timeout via a DefaultValue attribute.